# get values from json data using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i have a josn data like this

```
{
    "_id": "5319b5e10748a6078fe4f360",
    "acces": "172.1.6.2.18",
    "adapter": "Win 10",
    "flavour": "VM-IE8-001-preq1",
    "id": "67",
    "os": "VM-WIN7-64",
    "results": [{
        "\"test\":\"Connect_Disconnect\",\"os\":\"Windows NT\",\"report\":\"Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:OK<br>Delete Profile to the Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK<br>\"": ""
    }],
    "tests": "Test01"
}
```

From this
i have to get the values

```
adapter : "Win 10"
test : Connect_Disconnect
os :Windows NT

report : Verify Wireless Interface present and state is Disconnected:OK
Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK
Verify the State is Disconnected:OK
Delete Profile to the Client:OK
verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OK
```

How can i get the above values

i tried

```
 data.forEach(function (testreport) {

alert(testreport.results.test);// getting value as undefined

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could help you

```
 json_object._id;
 json_object.acces
 json_object.adapter
 json_object.flavour
 json_object.id
 json_object.os
 json_object.results
 json_object.results[0].os
 json_object.tests
```

Comment: not getting i tried your code...getting undfined values ` json_object.results[0].os`

Comment: i tried ` data.forEach(function (testreport) {

alert(testreport.results[0].test);// getting value as undefined

}`

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support JSON.parse()
     you can use javascript to parse the json or jquery

```
   var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
   obj = JSON.parse(json);
   alert(obj.count);
```

and  for the browsers which don't support json.parse() you can use

```
  var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```